# Using clause on template class

Tags: templates, using, c++03

To make referencing types easier you can bring individual types into the current scope with the using clause:

```
namespace MyCompany
{
    namespace MyProject
    {
        class MyType {};
        void myFunc(MyType const& obj) {}
    }
}

int main()
{
    using MyCompany::MyProject::MyType;
    using MyCompany::MyProject::myFunc;

    MyType  plop;
    myFunc(plop);
}
```

The problem is if the class is a template class (or function). Is it possible to bring these into the current scope without fully instantiating them?

```
namespace MyCompany
{
    namespace MyProject
    {
        template<typename T>
        class MyType {};

        template<typename T>
        void myFunc(MyType<T> const& obj) {}
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Can I bring the templates into scope?
    // Or do I need to fully instantiate each version in the using clause?
    using MyCompany::MyProject::MyType;  ????
    using MyCompany::MyProject::myFunc;  ????

    MyType  plop;
    myFunc(plop);
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use all the types in the namespace or just some? I don't know the answer to this question, but you can compromise by `using namespace MyProject;`

Comment: A good answer depends on whether you can use C++11 or not (as C++11 introduces template aliases).

Comment: I am still stuck with C++03 but answer for C++11 I am sure would be useful for other people so please add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both VC10 & gcc run the code ok with different instantiations after the using declaration.
So it seems the using declaration has brought the whole template to the scope.

Also in c++0x standard n3290 7.3.3 - 5

```
A using-declaration shall not name a template-id. [ Example:
struct A {
 template <class T> void f(T);
 template <class T> struct X { };
};
struct B : A {
 using A::f<double>; // ill-formed
 using A::X<int>; // ill-formed
};
```

which seems to suggest that using should not be used with specific template-id.